# Devonian Fish Diversity--What Would it Have Looked Like?

Tags: ecology, ichthyology, community-ecology, ecosystem

For 70 million years, the oceans, lakes and rivers of the world teemed with seven groups of fish:

[image]

Placodermi

[image]

Acanthodii

[image]

Agnatha

[image]

Chondrichthyes

[image]

Sarcopterygii

[image]

Actinopterygii

Now two of those groups have been extinct for hundreds of millions of years, but they were still a pretty big deal back then.

So by using modern fish as analogies, which niche(s) did which group of fish occupy during the Devonian Period?

Comment: A fascinating question, I wish I had time to delve into it, but it seems I am not the only one unable to do it justice at the moment.